# My laptop screen has patches all over it

Tags: laptop, lcd, laptop-repair

The screen of my laptop has this cloud like shapes covering all over it horizontally. As you can see in the attached photo it's not on the panel but inside the screen. I don't know how it happened. It looks like I just wiped the screen with a wet towel and it's drying up but it stays like this for a month or so.

Does anybody know why it might have happened and how I can fix this?

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I wiped the screen with a wet towel and patches are gone. I wasn't expecting this. I was thinking the screen is damaged. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your screen is working - I can see that . It is reasonable to asses that the computer is fundamentally working OK.

So the cloud like shapes is a screen hardware problem.

You can try updating the Video driver but that is very unlikely to fix the issue.

You need to replace the display or wait until you are ready to replace the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

An LCD screen is made in layers. The blotches appear to be something in between the layers, such as water, or separation ([delamination](http://macbookprolcd.com/macbook_pro_retina_a1502_13_early_2015_screen_lcd_delamination_antiglare_repair.html)) of the layers, perhaps due to exposure to high temperature. You can see images of some LCD issues at [Sony.com](https://www.sony.com/electronics/support/articles/00031219).

If it's water, you can try leaving the laptop in a **warm**, dry place (not more than 45°C or ~113°F) for a few days and look for any improvement -- if that helps, extend bake time but do *not* raise the temperature.

If it's due to delamination, you can try a (possibly expensive) commercial repair service, such as [AGirepair](https://agirepair.com/repair-industry/delamination-repair/), replacing the LCD panel (look up price online), or just living with it, since the damage is not bad.

Comment: It's not water and I didn't leave my computer under direct sunlight. Can it be the pressure of the keys when the lid is close? Because there was a rubber strip on the edges of the case but it's mostly gone due to wear.

Comment: Yes, delamination can also be caused by pressure and impact.